# How do I remove metadata / EXIF information from png and jpg images without recompressing the image?

Tags: php, apache

I'm using Apache + PHP on windows and I am currently using the GD method of removing metadata.

Is there any way to remove metadata within PHP without re-processing/drawing the image?

All I'm looking to do is remove the metadata without altering the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

As for what I remember, this is exacltly what [Photon for Wordpress](https://jetpack.com/support/photon/) does.
I found Automattics code for Photon here: https://code.trac.wordpress.org/browser/photon

The idea is that you buffer the image, and then looks at the characters in the buffer. Then by knowing what characters are reassembling the image, what characters that are reassembling the metadata, you can extract everything from the buffer that is not the metadata, and create the image from this new subset of the buffer.

You can look at especially their [class-jpeg-image.phpo file](https://code.trac.wordpress.org/browser/photon/class-jpeg-image.php), where they in their get_jpeg_header_data() method are finding the metadata.

I hope this can help you a little :)